# Install enormego's PhotoViewer for use in app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, installation

How do you install PhotoViewer found at  https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer? I have it downloaded I just don't know what to put into my app.

Comment: "We haven't yet had a chance to document EGOPhotoViewer, but you should be able to find everything you need in the header files and demo app."

Comment: At looked at the demo app and there seemed to be files in there that are not in the download

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop "EGOCache" and "EGOImageLoader" folders from the demo project into your project.Add "MessageUI.framework" into your project.

Then you can use the following code as in the demo.(instead of MyPhoto and MyPhotoSource class, we should use EGOQuickPhoto and EGOQuickPhotoSource ).Dats all....!!

```
        EGOQuickPhoto *photo = [[EGOQuickPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/66601193/cactus.jpg"] name:@" laksd;lkas;dlkaslkd ;a"];
        EGOQuickPhoto *photo2 = [[EGOQuickPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/425948730/DF-Star-Logo.png"] name:@"lskdjf lksjdhfk jsdfh ksjdhf sjdhf ksjdhf ksdjfh ksdjh skdjfh skdfjh "];
        EGOQuickPhotoSource *source = [[EGOQuickPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photo, photo2, photo, photo2, photo, photo2, photo, photo2, nil]];

        EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES];

        [photoController release];
        [photo release];
        [photo2 release];
        [source release];
```

Comment: hey, how does display the cancel button when we are presenting it modally and not push to view.